# KNP menu - highlight parent menu

Tags: knpmenubundle, symfony-3.1

With Symfony 3.1 and KNP menu bundle I build a 2 level menu tree.

The selected page gets highlighted within the menu.
As I am using a drop-down menu, I additionaly want the top level of menu being highlighted - basically the parent entry of my selected child.

No idea how to achieve this. Docs did not help so far. Any help appreciated.
Thanks Wolfram

Answer (score 1):

It is very late and I think you have already found the way, but in case someone is still looking for it, I am giving my answer.

Basically you can achieve this via the `setCurrent()` method. For example, I wanted to check it with my current routes. So, what I did was,

1. Added `request_stack` in my builder service. So my service was looking something like

   ```
   app.menu_builder:
       class: MyBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
       arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory", "@security.authorization_checker", '@request_stack']
       tags:
           - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createSideMenu, alias: side }
   ```
2. Now the constructor part in my MenuBuilder Class was looking something like

   ```
   use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

   class MenuBuilder
   {
       /**
        * @var FactoryInterface
        */
        private $factory;

       /**
        * @var TranslatorInterface
        */
        private $translator;

       /**
        * @var RequestStack
        */
        private $requestStack;

       /**
        * MenuBuilder constructor.
        * @param FactoryInterface $factory
        * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
        */
        public function __construct(
           FactoryInterface $factory,
           TranslatorInterface $translator,
           RequestStack $requestStack
       ) {
           $this->factory = $factory;
           $this->translator = $translator;
           $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
           $this->prefix = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_prefix');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then I created my menu for example:

   ```
   $menu->addChild('level1_1', array(
       'label' => "<span>Committee</span>",
       'uri' => '#',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   $menu['level1_1']->addChild('level2_1', array(
       'label' => "<span>Level 2 Number 1</span>",
       'route' => 'route_1',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   $menu['level1_1']->addChild('level2_2', array(
       'label' => "<span>Level 2 Number 2</span>",
       'route' => 'route_2',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   $menu->addChild('level1_2', array(
       'label' => "<span>Committee</span>",
       'uri' => '#',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   $menu['level1_2']->addChild('level2_3', array(
       'label' => "<span>Level 2 Number 3</span>",
       'route' => 'route_3',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   $menu['level1_2']->addChild('level2_4', array(
       'label' => "<span>Level 2 Number 4</span>",
       'route' => 'route_4',
       'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
   ));
   ```
4. Now comes the main part. After the menu object was ready for me, I mapped the routes with it's parent and set the parent active before returning the menu object.

   ```
   $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
   $routeName = $request->get('_route');

   switch ($routeName)
   {
       case 'route_1':
       case 'route_2':
           $menu['level1_1']->setCurrent(true);
           break;
       case 'route_3':
       case 'route_4':
           $menu['level1_2']->setCurrent(true);
           break;
   }
   ```

In place of this switch section, you can use your own login according to your needs. Hope this is clear enough to understand.